# Absolute URL in email generated using Velocity template

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc, velocity

I am working with a Spring web application that needs to generate an e-mail using a Velocity template. I have the following configuration in the Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/,classpath:/velocity" />
</bean>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.mycompany" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mailer" class="com.mycompany.utils.EmailManager">
    <constructor-arg name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    <constructor-arg name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
</bean>
```

This set up works well and all context data is resolved correctly to generate the email. However one variable **`$link.contextURL`** does not resolve and I need this because the email includes an absolute URL back to the web application. I could have hard-coded the URL, but that obviously is not seamless across a DEV/UAT/PROD environment. I could include the URL in the context data fed to the template, but I want to leverage the popular **LinkTool** Velocity extension, which allows me to leverage the `$link.contextURL` variable. Is there any way to facilitate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The velocity has got no http-request context when evaluating your mail template and the complete URL cannot be computed without it. I am afraid you have to include the URL into the context data or find a way to supply http-request context for the evaluation of mail template.

Comment: Since I had the injected `HttpServletRequest` object in my Spring MVC controller, I ended up getting the URL via `request.getRequestURL()` and extracted the required portion of the URL from that. Thanks.